# Converting an int to a char in PHP has a different output in C#

Tags: c#, php, char

I've got a `PHP` script which I have manually converted to `C#`. The output of the `hexSalt` and the `hexFull` variable do print the same but the ouput of variable `data` is different. I have discovered that the problem persists in converting the `int` variable to `char`. How can these be different?

I have tried in `C#` to convert them and to cast them in multiple ways like: 

`Char.ConvertFromUtf32(int)`, `Convert.ToChar(int)`, `(char)int`

but those are displaying the same incomplete `C#` output.

## C#

```
string data = "";
string saltFull = "";
string hexFull = "";

char[] saltChars = salt.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < (salt.Length / 2); i++)
{
    string hexSalt = saltChars[i * 2].ToString() + saltChars[(i * 2) + 1].ToString();
    saltFull += hexSalt;

    int hex = int.Parse(hexSalt, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    hexFull += hex.ToString();

    char chr = (char)hex;
    data += chr;
}

Response.Write(saltFull + "<br />"); // Same output
Response.Write(hexFull + "<br />"); // Same output
Response.Write(data); // Almost the same output...

// Output of variable data, the converted int to char.
// ¸:}P/C{_ëóCZÔfPüY£Y,Ö]·î~9ªuJb®é­I[p¢?0ZÖµz²ð4
```

## PHP

```
$data = "";
$saltFull = "";
$hexFull = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($salt) / 2; $i++) {
    $hexSalt = $salt[$i * 2] . $salt[($i * 2) + 1];
    $saltFull .= $hexSalt;

    $hex = hexdec($hexSalt);
    $hexFull .= $hex;

    $chr = chr($hex);
    $data .= $chr;
}

echo $saltFull . "<br />"; // Same output
echo $hexFull . "<br />"; // Same output
echo $data; // Almost the same output...

// Output of variable data, the converted int to char.
// ¸ˆ:}Pž/CŽ”“{_ëóCZ‹ÔfP€üY£Y,Ö]·î~9ªuJb®é­I[p¢?0ZÖµz²ð…4
```

---

**Additional information:**

- I am testing it in the same browser
- I am running both codes on the same server.
- I cannot edit the PHP code
- I cannot change the salt

Comment: How do you compare the two salts?

Comment: I open the two pages in two tabs in the same browser, tested it with multiple browsers (IE, Chrome etc.). As you can see in the code I use `echo` and `Response.Write()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!!

```
byte[] chr = BitConverter.GetBytes(hex);
data += Encoding.Default.GetString(chr);
```

I converted the `int` to a `byte[]` array and I used the `GetString(byte[])` method to get the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change data as a List of Character.

```
List<char> data = new List<char>();
string saltFull = "";
string hexFull = "";

char[] saltChars = salt.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < (salt.Length / 2); i++)
{
    string hexSalt = saltChars[i * 2].ToString() + saltChars[(i * 2) + 1].ToString();
    saltFull += hexSalt;

    int hex = int.Parse(hexSalt, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    hexFull += hex.ToString();

    char chr = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(hex);
    data.Add(chr);
}

Response.Write(saltFull + "<br />"); // Same output
Response.Write(hexFull + "<br />"); // Same output

char[] dataArray = data.ToArray();
Response.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
```

Strings in C# are saved in UTF-16 encode and it could corrupt byte-strings. When you use binary strings I suggest you to use byte[] or char[] and not strings

Comment: Sorry, could you write an example salt?

Comment: The problem is solved, check my answer, I thank you for your effort :) !